# Changing status data (true/false) on Firebase by web

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, iot

I can't change the status data on my Firebase project with the HTML site and using javascript (.js) to connect with my Firebase project. I've made checkbox to change the status data on Firebase. But it can't change the data value on Firebase. I've change id checkbox, but there is no result. Anyone please help me. I am newbie. This is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description">
        <meta name="author">
        <title>
            Web Kontrol
        </title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link href="assets/css/sh-default.css" rel="stylesheet" default-stylesheet="true" type="text/css">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body style="cursor: auto;">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button><a class="navbar-brand" href>Web Kontrol Lampu</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li>
                        <a data-target="#login" href>Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <!--<li>
                        <a data-target="#register" href>Signup</a>
                    </li>-->
                    <li>
                        <a data-target="#lists" href>Control</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="logout" href>Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome"></div>
    <div class="container tab default" id="login">
        <form class="form-signin" role="form">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">
                <em class="stackhive-marker"></em>Login to Your Account
            </h2>
            <hr>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="" id="login-email"><input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
            required="" id="login-password">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="login-btn">
                Login
            </button>
            <hr>
            <div class="status alert alert-info hide"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container tab hide" id="register">
        <form class="form-signin" role="form">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">
                Daftar Akun Baru
            </h2>
            <hr>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required="" autofocus="" id="name"><input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required=""
            autofocus="" id="email"><input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="signup-btn">
                Masuk !
            </button>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <div class="status alert alert-info hide"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container tab hide" id="lists">
        <div class="status alert alert-info hide"></div><br>
        <h1>Kontrol Lampu</h1>
        <div align="center">

            <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round-1" type="checkbox">
            <input id="cmn-toggle-2" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round-2" type="checkbox">
        </div><!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.3/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./firebasefunctions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="./script-coba.js"></script> -->
</body>
```

And this .js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //this URL to my FIrebase project
  var ref = new Firebase("https://firesmartlamp.firebaseio.com/devices/smartlamp/parameters/");

  /*****************************************************************
   Get the status on Firebase
  ******************************************************************/
  ref.once("value", function(res) {
    var status = res.child("state").val(); //state is my data on Firebase
    $('#cmn-toggle-1').attr('checked', status); //cmn-toggle-1 is my checkbox id
    console.log("Statusnya: " +status)
  });

  ref.once("value", function(res) {
    var status2 = res.child("state2").val();
    $('#cmn-toggle-2').attr('checked', status);
    console.log("Statusnya: " +status2)
  });

  /*****************************************************************
   Sync to firebase
  ******************************************************************/
  ref.on("child_changed", function(res) {

    var states = res.val();
    $('#cmn-toggle-1').prop('checked', states);
    console.log("Cek: " +states)

  });

  ref.on("child_changed", function(res) {

    var states2 = res.val();
    $('#cmn-toggle-2').prop('checked', states2);
    console.log("Cek: " +states2)

  });        

 /*****************************************************************
   Update value, changed status of Switch 
  ******************************************************************/
  $('#cmn-toggle-1').on('change', function(){ 
     if(this.checked) 
      {
          console.log("On")
          ref.update({ state: true }); //true and false are value of data on Firebase
      }
      else{
          console.log("Off")
          ref.update({ state: false });
      }
    });

  $('#cmn-toggle-2').on('change', function(){ 
     if(this.checked) 
      {
          console.log("On")
          ref.update({ state2: true });
      }
      else{
          console.log("Off")
          ref.update({ state2: false });
      }
    });

});
```

Comment: Are you connecting to firebase with your app's details like [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)? Also, you're using version 2 I notice. If you're just starting out, use the current version 3.1, otherwise you must make sure you're using the legacy docs.

Comment: Are you getting an error in your browser console?

Comment: Also, I see you have included jQuery UI. Have you included jQuery itself?

Comment: @DavidGilbertson i've done all of it, but still no result

Comment: yes, i have. And there is no log on console

Comment: Put a console.log() before the first `ref.once()` to make sure it's actually running. If ya, then try changing your ref to just `Firebase("https://firesmartlamp.firebaseio.com/");` and `console.log()` inside the the `once()` callback. Does that work? Try and strip the example down to the simplest possible code, make it easy for us :)

Comment: `The connection to wss://s-usc1c-nss-123.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=firesmartlamp was interrupted while the page was loading.`
I've tried to add console log, and I get this error on console

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle/jsbin, so that we can take a look at it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen https://jsbin.com/becuqejito/1/edit?html,css,js this link I reproduce the problem in jsbin

Comment: I've made the jsbin work, it wasn't including jQuery and Firebase. Next time make sure to include your dependencies in there so that it reproduces the problem you're asking about. The easier you make it for us to help you, the more likely you are to get an answer quickly. I'll write an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing all kinds of data access patterns, so I cleaned those up in your [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/vebizu/edit?html,js,output) and made it work. The reading from Firebase is now simply:

```
  /*****************************************************************
   Sync with firebase
  ******************************************************************/
  ref.child("state").on("value", function(res) {
    var states = res.val();
    $('#cmn-toggle-1').prop('checked', states);
  });

  ref.child("state2").on("value", function(res) {
    var states2 = res.val();
    $('#cmn-toggle-2').prop('checked', states2);
  });
```

So we have the two state properties (`state` and `state2`) and attach a value listener to each. That means the callbacks will be invoked "immediately" with the current value and then once whenever the property changes.